# Get an image from a web service

Tags: javascript, web-services

I want to get an image from a web service. The connection to the web service is done successfully, but the image is not opened in my page.
The link that I get is the link of the image that I want to open.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/Config/phonegap-0.9.3.js"></script>  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />  

<script>
var ws_key="....";
var PHP_AUTH_USER="....";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET","http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/images/products/10/50?PHP_AUTH_USER="+PHP_AUTH_USER+"&ws_key="+ws_key,true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(request.readyState==4)
        {
            alert("Status is:  "+request.status);
            if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)
            {
                response  = request.responseXML;
            lien="http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/images/products/10/50"




             }
         }

    }
    request.send();

</script>


</head>
<body>

<img src=lien height="150" width="150">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is in your Ajax response? A URL?

Comment: I have checked the response I found [object]

Comment: Use a debugger, like firebug, open the NET tab and look at the ajax response. You should be getting back a URL to the image.

Comment: But when I open the Url: http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/images/products/10/50 on a navigator, then I enter the Login and passwd, the image is opened

Comment: Is the web service on the same domain as the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your HTML.

```
<img src="http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/images/products/10/50?PHP_AUTH_USER=yourpassword&ws_key=yourlogin ">
```